# XSS Works, but only 1 word

Tags: javascript, php, sql, xss

Maybe it's an weird question but I'll try to explain it as good I can. Currently I'm pentesting a website, for xss (cross site scripting).
First I just tried, `<script>alert(1)</script>` and it resulted in `[removed]alert(1)[removed]`, but also `<scr<script>` and those kinds of things, and I tried much more.

Now I finally got a working one:
`<input onfocus=alert("test") autofocus>`
and yes it really spits out 'test' but when i type `alert(document.cookie)` it already doesn't spit anything out anymore, also
`<input onfocus=alert("test lol") autofocus>`
doesn't spit anything out anymore, but like how can I now get the cookie? And why is it spitting out test, or ahihawiejawije but not ahjiahwe jijaja or test test, just one word? Also integers WORKS.

Also all html code, I try to in does work like `<div>` or `<iframes>` so how can I get the `document.cookie spitted` out on the page?

This is where I enter the XSS code:
https://gyazo.com/d260e065a305941e92a414a321501134

And when I save it I can view it on this page:
https://gyazo.com/723c1bff1d6fb7f3341a5b19cadcd264

But since the document.cookie one isn't working it'll just show an input bar, but when I replace the document.cookie just with "lol" it gives me this:
"lol" (can't put more than 2 links bcz reputation) so it is working with lol.

So how is it possible that like one word, or one big word like AAAAAAAAA is working but not just  2 words like aaa aaa or document.cookie?

Comment: You need to post your code, there's no way we can guess what you're doing.

Comment: It puts the text in the DOM source or it alerts it? Attribute values should be quoted so after the first word it probably is no longer consider the attributes value. This doesn't seem PHP relevant.

Comment: sorry i'll add the examples of the page in a second.

Comment: okey added it into the question, so someone knows it?

Comment: @JelmerdeVries You didn't give us the code. The backend code that escapes the code is important, not the frontend, and you used *screenshots*, which are entirely useless to us.

Comment: I don't have access to the backend, I'm just curious why printing out helloworld does work and hello world not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm just curious why printing out helloworld does work and hello world not.

The space, because of the messed-up HTML, starts another attribute.

Take a look in Chrome's inspector and the syntax highlighting makes it clear what's happening:

```
<input onfocus=alert("test lol") autofocus>
```

becomes:

[image]

Chrome attempts to fix the HTML, and `lol")` becomes another attribute. (I have no idea where the `autofocus` goes...) Nothing to do with the site's XSS protection (or lack thereof), just how the browser interprets the bad HTML.

Comment: but why does alert(document.cookie) doesnt work than?

Comment: Oh now I understand, this is an really good answer ! Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi @JelmerdeVries. If this, or any answer, has solved your question please consider [accepting it](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answer-er and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.